# An interesting combinatorial property

Tags: combinatorics, probabilistic-method, hypergraphs

For an integer $n$, let $[n] = \{1,\cdots,n\}$. A family $N$ of subsets of $[n]$ , i.e. $N\subset 2^{[d]}$ is said to have **Property B(i,j)** if the following holds:

For every $I,J\subset [n]$ such that $\vert I\vert =i, \vert J\vert=j$ and $I\cap J=\emptyset$, there is a $K\in N$ such that $I\cap K = \emptyset$ and $J\subset K$. My question is that how small the size of such a family can be? I suspect that the answer is $f=f(i,j,n)$ for some function $f$ that depends on n only polynomially(even be independent of n). I am sure this is a known problem.

Towards proving the upper bound, I apply the usual **probabilistic method**: pick $f$ random  subsets of $[n]$ and put them into $N$. A random subset $R$ of $[n]$ is computed by picking every element of $[n]$ with probability $p$ (to be determined). Note that the number of $I,J\subset [n]$ such that $\vert I\vert =i, \vert J\vert=j$ and $I\cap J=\emptyset$ is $A=$ $n\choose i$ $n-i\choose j$. After some calculation and applying union bound, I get that the probability that $N$ has **Property B(i,j)** is at least

$1-A\big(1-(1-p)^ip^j\big)^f$

Now for specific values of $p$ and $f$, this should be non-zero. I fail to find such values.

Towards the other end of the spectrum, what is the lower bound of the size of such a family?

Comment: Of course $f(1,1,n)=$ the least $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\binom m{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\ge n$.

Comment: Note that the statement "there is a family of $m$ subsets of $[n]$ with property $B(i,j)$" is equivalent to thestatement "there is a family of $n$ subsets of $[m]$ such that the intersection of $j$ members of the family is never contained in the union of $i$ other members of the family". Thus your property $B(2,1)$ was in effect the subject of [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214766/maximal-number-of-subsets-in-1-dots-n-such-that-neither-is-contained-in-a/) and property $B(n,1)$ is addressed in the second paper cited in the answer to that question.

Comment: You are on the right track. It is easy to find values $f,p$ for which  $1-A(1-p^i(1-p)^j)^f>0$. Simply choose the smallest $f$ for which$$f>\frac{\log A}{-\log \big(1-p^i(1-p)^j\big)}.$$ The next question is; how do you choose $p$ so that the resulting $f$ is minimized?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @bof I will look into the links.  I think calculas can be used to minimize RHS. Is this a well known problem? What about the lower bound of such family?

Comment: For the upper bound, you should asymptotically get $C\log n$, where $C=\frac{i+j}{-\log(1-i^ij^j/(i+j)^{i+j})}$. The best lower bound I can do is constant. $\tag*{}$Sketch of proof: each pair $(I,J)$ needs a $K$ for which $I\subseteq K\subset ([n]\setminus J)$. Count the number of pairs $(I,J)$ satisfied by a particular $K$, in terms of $|K|$. Lower bound is $\binom{n}i\binom{n-i}{j}\Big/(\text{max # $(I,J)$ per $K$)}$. $\tag*{}$ I will post an answer if I can get lower and upper bounds to match.

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes, I failed to see that $A$ is asymptotically $n^{i+j}$. From that one gets that the best value of $p$ is $\frac{j}{i+j}$. As for the lower bound,  would it not be $J\subseteq K \subseteq ([n]\setminus I)$. Let me know if I follow your reasoning, since any such family must cover all of a $A$ choices of $(I,J)$, we must have $A \leq f\cdot \text{max # $(I,J)$ per $K$}$. But the latter is $\binom{n-\vert K\vert}{i}\binom{\vert K\vert}{j}\leq n^{i+j}$.

Comment: (1) Sorry, I mixed up $i$ & $j$. (2) Furthermore, $\binom{n-|K|}i\binom{|K|}j\approx \frac{(n-k)^i k^j}{i!j!}$, which by calculus is maximized when $k=n\cdot \frac{j}{i+j}$.